# Could not find method compile for args

Tags: gradle, nlp

I'm trying to download CoreNLP in my build.gradle like this:

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
 }

  dependencies {
    classpath "org.elasticsearch.gradle:build-tools:${elasticsearchVersion}"
      compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.6.0'
      compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.6.0', classifier: 'models'

  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=edu.stanford.nlp, name=stanford-corenlp, version=3.6.0}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I tried to change `compile` to `implementation` and I'm getting the same error but `method implementation()`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add `Java` dependencies into the `buildscript` dependencies (that's why it complains).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.elasticsearch.gradle:build-tools:${elasticsearchVersion}"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

the module-level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp
    compile "edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.9.2"
    compile "edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-parser:3.9.2"
}
```

no clue about the models, because there are a few kinds of available, which are all pretty dated.

you still could attempt to reference `"edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.9.2:models"`.

`implementation` & `api` might be specific to Android DSL.

Comment: What do you mean module-level? I just tried pasting your second code snippet right after the first one (after the close bracket of `allprojects`) and I'm getting the same exact error

Comment: @ninesalt I've provided both parts for a reason (they also work within the same file, in case there are no modules present in the project).

Comment: No need to be hostile lol. Yes I did read your answer multiple times but I'm new to gradle so I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: @ninesalt what I mean is, that the first part corrects the error and the second part are the actual dependencies in their current version. `allprojects` might not be required, when there is only one `build.gradle`, but the nested inside `repositories` are.

Comment: Well yes thats what I understood (and tried) but i'm still getting the same error. Doesn't matter anyway, I'm not going to use coreNLP now.

Comment: @ninesalt you might be missing `apply plugin: 'java'` of `plugins {id 'java'}`... because that's where the `compile` comes from.